# How to update user except registration date in asp.net 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have a class that includes the registration date for users. when I want to edit a user I have to change the registration date too. how can I avoid this and update my user without changing the register date?

this is my update method:

```
public void Update(MemberModel member)
{
    member.RegistrationDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    db.Entry(member).State = 
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

And this is my model:

```
public class MemberModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Family { get; set; }
    public string? RegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
    public string? NationalId { get; set; }
    public MembershipTypeId Membership { get; set; }
    public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public GenderEnum Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You should have two property `RegistrationDate` and `RegistrationLastUpdatedOn`

Comment: Could you please share your `MemberModel` details

Comment: What are you asking? How to automatically update the `RegistrationDate`? Or how to avoid modifying it - in which case, just *don't* set anything to it? BTW, *NEVER* use strings to store dates. Use the correct type insted, ie DateTime or DateTimeOnly.

Comment: If you don't want to change a property, why are you assigning `DateTime.Now.ToString();` to it?

Comment: If you want to "automatically" update the `RegistrationDate` every time an object is saved, you can use a [SaveChanges interceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#savechanges-interception) to find all modified entities of a certain type and update their fields. In older EF Core versions you had to [override SaveChanges](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2022/03/16/auto-updating-created-updated-and-deleted-timestamps-in-entity-framework/) to do the same

Comment: if I don't use this, the registration date turns to null in my database

Comment: BTW the entire `Update` method is wrong. In fact, the call to `SaveChanges` is a **major** bug that completely breaks EF Core's transaction and concurrency behavior. When you load an object in EF Core *all* changes are detected and tracked and persisted when `SaveChanges` is called, in a single transaction, at the very end of a request. The only thing you need to do to "rollback" is simply to *not* call `SaveChanges`. If you call `SaveChanges` multiple times you can't roll them back without starting an explicit transaction. Which in turn means you now need an explicit long-lived connection

Comment: No, I don't want to update my registrationdate . actually, I want to leave it behind and don't change it. but I don't know how

Comment: First, fix the type bug. *DON'T* use strings for dates. Make the field a *non*-nullable Date field. Second, if you want a default value, specify that in the model *and* the database - specify that the field has a default value. Third - where does `member` come from? Why is its `RegistrationDate` property null? Why not set the current date when you create that object, eg in the constructor or as an initial property value?

Answer (score 0):

First,  fix the type bug. DON'T use strings for dates. There's no real way to ensure the strings stored in a string 'date' are not garbage. You can't even assume they're in the same format - is `4/7/2022` April 7 or July 4? You can't even sort such strings unless they're in a format like ISO8601, ie YYYY-MM-DD. Even that takes more space than a strongly typed `date`, `datetime` or even `datetimeoffset` field though, and can't take advantage of the date optimizations available in most databases.

If you want the `RegistrationDate` property to have a default value the easiest way is to specify that value as its initial value, eg in the property initializer or object contstructor.

```
public class MemberModel
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string? Name { get; set; }
     public string? Family { get; set; }
     public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now
     ...
}
```

You can also specify that the field will have a default value if another isn't provided through a DEFAULT constraint in the database. In EF Core you can [specify the default value or formula](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#default-values) for a property in `OnModelCreating` :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<MemberModel>()
        .Property(b => b.RegistrationDate)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I Edit My Member without changing the RegistrationDate ? I want to write an update method that can change all of my properties "except" RegistrationDate